# The file “UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate” could not be unlocked. React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, error-handling

**Xcode full error**

*The file is stored in a read-only volume. Try making the volume writable or copying the file to another volume.*

[image]

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to change hard drive “read-only” permission on a Mac after that you can access this:

from this url you can solve your issue:

https://macpaw.com/how-to/hard-drive-read-only-permission

Comment: My hard drive is Destroyed, That's why I am facing this issue